# Question on Look up Enum member in C#

Tags: c#, enums, c#-2.0

How can I rapidly look up my enum obj and find out the enum obj include/not include another input member?

```
public enum myen
{
    S1,
    S2,
    S3，
}

other member like s2 or s4.

 intput   s2 -> true;  // included
 input    s4 -> false;  // not include
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This is very psuedo-code and not very clear. What do you mean by input member?

Comment: @Josh, I should use *is Defined or not* as keywords in my original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) or use Enum.GetNames based on what is the input that you have.

```
// => true
Console.WriteLine( Enum.GetNames(typeof(myen)).Any(member => member.Equals("S3")) );
Console.WriteLine( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myen), "S3" ));
Console.WriteLine( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myen), 2 ));

// => false
Console.WriteLine( Enum.GetNames(typeof(myen)).Any(member => member.Equals("S4")) );
Console.WriteLine( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myen), "S4" ));
Console.WriteLine( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myen), 3 ));
```

Comment: I can't find the method of `IsDefined`. Where it located? Thank you.

Comment: @Nano - It is a static method on the Enum class. Ensure that you are 'using System' in your source file so that the System namespace is reachable.

Comment: That's not "rapid" though, assuming this is an efficiency issue.

Comment: I found it. Thanks for your details input.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend writing your own version of `Enum.IsDefined()` that's based on generics, and that caches results instead of boxing and unboxing the values; that can result in the "rapid" lookup you stated in your question.

Comment: +1 it uses reflection - so consider other options before embedding it it in a perf sensitive/freq called area.

Comment: It uses reflection, but that's actually not all that bad if you're doing the same kind of check (same enum) frequently, since the objects are cached internally; it becomes significant if the cache runs out (because different enums are being checked one after another) and the reflection actually has to occur.